# Difference between datetimes in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 dates from mysql with datetime format.

Date 1 is:

```
"2012/09/28 09:28:00" (column name is departure_date)
```

and Date 2 is:

```
"2012/09/29 10:48:00" (column name is return_date)
```

So how to get a result like this: `"25 hours 20 minutes"`

I don't care about the seconds.

I'm using MySQL and PHP for the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it example by this:

```
$date1 = "2012/09/28 09:28:00";
$date2 = "2012/09/29 10:48:00";

$difference = abs(strtotime($date2)-strtotime($date1));

$hours = floor($difference / (60*60));
$minutes = floor(($difference - $hours * 60*60) / 60);

echo "{$hours} hours {$minutes} minutes";
```

And it will give you exactly what are you looking for:

> 25 hours 20 minutes

Answer (score 6):

Date difference function already exists

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-10-04 11:26:00','2007-10-04 11:50:00')
```

Also you can try TimeDiff

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-10-05 12:10:18','2007-10-05 16:14:59') AS duration;
```

So in your case you have the option to use these two functions like this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(departure_date,return_date) AS duration;
SELECT DATEDIFF(departure_date,return_date) AS duration;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2012/09/28 09:28:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2012/09/29 10:48:00");

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->format('%d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

Check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for the format.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select concat(substr(mt,1,locate('.',mt)-1),' hours') hours,
       concat(ceil((substr(mt,locate('.',mt)+1) * .60)/100 ),' minutes') 
                                                                     as minutes
from (
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                      '2012/09/28 09:28:00','2012/09/29 10:48:00')/60 as mt)a
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2997)